# Как спарсить такой формат от 1С

Tags: 1с, php

Экспортировал из 1С такой вот TXT файл, в нём такая штука. Как это называется, и как его лучше парсить с помощью PHP?

```
{"СписокЗначений",{{{"Строка","ДисконтныеКарты"},"Идентификатор","0"},
```

Comment: Что хотелось-бы получит в php?

Comment: Массив данных, который можно было обойти циклом

Comment: Что-то похожее на JSON. Эту строку можно отобразить как:

    Array (
      [0] = > "Список значений",
      [1] = > Array(
         [0] = > Array(
           [0] = > Array (
             [0] = > "Строка",
             [1] = > "ДисконтныеКкарты"
           ),
           [1] = > "Идентификатор",
           [2] = > 0
         )
      ),
    )

А как парсить, ну надо писать парсер :D

Comment: спасибо КЭП :DDD

Comment: Для написания парсера, думаю, стоит почитать про стэки...

Comment: Да тут надо не перестараться с рекурсией =)

Comment: Решил без рекурсии))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function parseIt($str){
    $steck = Array();
    while(strlen($str) > 0){
        if($str{0} == "{"){
            array_push($steck, $str{0});
            $str=substr($str, 1);
        }elseif($str{0}=='"'){ 
            $str=substr($str, 1);
            $pos=strpos($str, '"');
            $strsub=substr($str, 0, $pos);
            array_push($steck, $strsub);
        $str=substr($str, $pos+1);
        }elseif($str{0}==","){
            $str=substr($str, 1);
        }elseif($str{0}=="}") {
            $i=0;
            while($pop!="{"){
            $pop=array_pop($steck);
                if($pop!="{")$tmp_arr[++$i]=$pop;
             }
        $pop="";
             array_push($steck,array_reverse($tmp_arr));
             unset($tmp_arr);
             $str = substr($str, 1);
        }
    }
    return $steck[0];
}

var_dump(parseIt($str));
```

проверено...

Answer (score 1):

Это внутреннее представление данных в 1С
Спарсить такой формат очень просто, для этого используется функция **ЗначениеИзСтрокиВнутр**

Единственая трудность может быть только в том, что восстановить таким образом значения можно только в той конфигурации, в которой выгрузка значений в этот формат была произведена, ну или ордственных.

Comment: Это вы про программирование в 1С, а мне нужно этот файл спарсить с помощью PHP.

Comment: Вообще странный способ обработки данных. Что мешает получить из 1С данные в человеческом формате? Обработчиков выгрузки данных в инете просто тьма.